# How to fix the error "Notice: Undefined variable: storeId in /catalog/product/special.phtml"

Tags: magento-1.9, php, error, template

My system.log file filled with full of the error "Notice: Undefined variable: storeId  in /catalog/product/special.phtml on line 26"

See the line 26 here:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($_product->getId());
```

How can I fix the issue?

Note: the error came up after I installed the following patches: SUPEE-6285-1.9.1v2, SUPEE-6482-1.9.1.1, SUPEE-6788-1.9.1.1, SUPEE-7405-1.9.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line before line 26:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
```

Comment: It works... Thank you so much... But there's is another error now... I will add the error to the question now.... plz let me know if you have any suggestions.